# How long can cooked food be safely stored at room/warm temperature?

Tags: food-safety, meat

If I leave fully-cooked food (particularly meat) out at warm temperature - say on the counter or in a crock pot that's been turned off -  how long will it stay safe to eat?

Does it make any difference if I re-cook the food afterward?

Comment: @aaronut: I always find this one interesting, especially for slow-cooking. Generally, a slow cooked meal will be cooked effectively sterile (3-6 hours at 150+ kills damn near everything), thus if it is prevented from bacterial combination it should be fine **forever** (a la Pasteur's flasks (http://science.howstuffworks.com/innovation/scientific-experiments/scientific-method5.htm)). I'd be interested in seeing how that played in the real world, but I've never found anyone who actually did the experiment...They always assume contamination occurs.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy: I'd generally agree that the insulated environment of a crock pot is less hospitable to bacterial recontamination than open air, but no amount of time at 65° C will render the environment sterile. In particular, the spores from spore-forming bacteria such as *B. Cereus* (rice/pasta) and almost all of the *Clostridium* species can survive boiling at 100° C. That's why low-acid foods have to be pressure-canned before storage. The spores aren't normally dangerous when eaten, but if they survive the cooking (and they will) then bacteria will start to grow again as it cools.

Answer (score 26):

The [USDA](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/how-temperatures-affect-food/ct_index) has this to say on it:

> **Storing Leftovers**
>   One of the most common causes of foodborne illness is improper cooling of cooked foods. Because bacteria are everywhere, even after food is cooked to a safe internal temperature, they can be reintroduced to the food and then reproduce. For this reason leftovers must be put in shallow containers for quick cooling and refrigerated within 2 hours.

You'll find similar statements from government agencies around the world.  The safe limit for raw *or* cooked food is **2 hours** in the danger zone (40-140° F or 4.4-60° C).

If you're a restaurant owner or cook, you **must** follow this rule, hold hot foods above 60° C and quick-cool other foods before refrigerating.  If you are not working in a professional capacity then you are not *legally* required to follow it, but if you are serving **guests** then it would be **irresponsible** (and possibly actionable, if someone gets sick) to do otherwise.

If you're an individual serving only yourself, then take whatever liberties and break whatever rules you want; it's your food, and your body.  But there's no table or chart anyone can give you; there's no single specific point at which a food transitions from "not entirely safe" to "probably will kill you" because it depends entirely on the food, the environment, your immune system, and a plethora of other variables. The rule is 2 hours, *period*; any longer and there is *some* non-trivial risk to your health.

**Some hints, tips, and warnings:**

- The 2-hour rule is a conservative estimate with a safety margin. Don't ask what that margin is. It's like asking what the "real" speed limit is on a posted road; you might know from experience, but it could change depending on circumstances and exceeding it by *any* amount means you take your chances and accept the risks.
- Don't put large, hot items (such as an entire pot of soup or chili) directly into the fridge. The residual heat will warm up and potentially spoil *other* items in the refrigerator.
- To quickly cool large cooked items, use an ice-water bath and/or divide them into small containers. (Note: Don't use an ice-water bath for cast iron.)
- **Don't assume that re-cooking an improperly-stored item will make it safe.** Most bacteria produce protein toxins, which are actually the primary agents responsible for food poisoning, and several of these toxins are heat-resistant. Cooking will not kill or inactivate these toxins and eating the re-cooked food will still make you sick.
- Don't assume that cooking "kills everything" and that a cooked food or cooking surface is absolutely sterile. Cooking kills *enough* to make the food safe to eat, but some organisms - such as bacterial spores from *bacillus* and *clostridium* - can survive the cooking process and immediately start producing more bacteria. Sous-vide bags, crock pots, etc. are *not* safe environments for cooked food in the temperature danger zone.

Answer (score 5):

UK Food Hygiene Regulations (see UK FSA web-site) state that cold foods must be kept at 8°C or below and hot foods must be kept at 63°C or above.  This is a legal requirement throughout the UK.

However when you are serving or displaying food, you can keep it out of temperature control for a limited period of time:  Cold foods can be kept above 8°C for up to four hours. You should only do this once. If any food is left after this time, you should throw it away or keep it chilled at 8°C or below until it is used.  Hot foods can be kept below 63°C for up to two hours. You should only do this once. If any food is left after this time, you should throw it away, reheat it to 63°C or above (82°C in Scotland), or cool below 8°C  This applies to the UK with relatively temperate ambient temperatures - there have been nasty food poisoning cases where poorly prepared foods have been held in hot cars for relatively short periods.

Having said this, cold foods should always be served cold as soon as possible, and hot foods served hot as soon as possible after preparation.

Answer (score -2):

Potted meat, meat held in hardened (( Rendered/clarified) animal fat, can last for quite some time without going bad.

EASILY SEVERAL days without refrigeration ! ! At normal room temp. 72F...

The problem with this method is that AIR on the surface of the fat can oxidize the lard and make it go rancid, but that takes much more than 4 days.

If you put saran wrap on top of the hard lard and poured water you could move all the air out, and preserve the lard even longer.

Lard potted meat using proper snow white lard or double clarified butter can last for months and months in the cool cellar or ground ! !

My grandmother used lard potted meat that was over a year old kept in the fridge ! !

No frezer burn, tasted amazing ! !

It was PERFECT ! !

Dont try this in direct sunlight of a hot summer day.

Pickled meats last a long time, pickled eggs...

You can pasteurize many different ways.

Bacterial spores can be killed by  double flash pasteurization, though its usually done 3 times.

New methods are being invented, especially a modified microwave which could kill 100% of bacteria is VERY promising.  Lasts 10x longer than irradiated food ! !

I ate 50 year old bacon( fetal pig) that was kept in pure ethanol when i was locked in a basement storage facility of a university during summer break at Indiana university.

As far as i know you can eat 100+ year old specimens preserved in alcohol.  Besides being tasteless and getting drunk it was fine.

Comment: Potted meat might be stored at British room temperature, but American room temp tends to be much warmer.  I know there are more answers on here about preservation via fat, but they tend to be voted down because of potential food safety concerns.  If done correctly, you're pasteurizing the meat, and then sealing it from exposure.  See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8070/67

Comment: Aside from the gross factor of eating the fetal pig specimen, it is also very dangerous to drink or eat meat preserved in lab grade ethanol. Lab grade ethanol will rarely be 100% and will often contain amounts of methanol. Methanol even in small amounts will blind(10mL) or kill you(25mL).

Answer (score -3):

I left a crockpot full of broth, smoked turkey, turnips seasonings  and spices(Onions red green & yellow peppers) mistakenly, out overnight & it was covered. That was around 8pm. I went somewheres, returned at 10am. Yeah, it was left all night long. But I said, "bump that", reboiled it, threw in some sun dried tomatoes & fresh spinach, threw some hot sauce on it, served over rice and I ate it, damn everything these germophobes say! Then I washed it down with some ice-cold gingerale!

Comment: This just means you got lucky once. It doesn't mean this is at all safe.

Comment: This has been flagged as not an answer a few times; in my view it is an answer (it's implying it's safe) it's just not a *good* answer, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: Though I do the same myself, as I'd only be responsible for killing... me;) I'd hesitate to delete it or even downvote any further. -3 answers cannot be seen by new users, so at -2 it serves its purpose.