# Sloppy joe mix cooked with hamburger and was left on the counter for 2 hours.....should i throw it away?

Tags: food-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can cooked food be safely stored at room/warm temperature?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/how-long-can-cooked-food-be-safely-stored-at-room-warm-temperature)

I made a large pot of sloppy joe mix with hamburger in it and after it was cooked put it in my crockpot on low for my boys to eat when they got home because i was leaving,i was gone a little over 2 hours and the boys had put the sauce into another pan to put it away and forgot to do so it sat on the counter for over 2 hours....should i throw it away?

Comment: Was it hot when they put it into the pan? How much more than two hours are we talking about here?

Comment: This question isn't an *exact* duplicate of the one I linked, but it's pretty darn close, and Aaronut's answer there completely covers you: two hours is the limit. It's a conservative one, but if you go past it, there's risk.

Comment: Meat is meat... it's a dupe. I wouldn't bat an eye over 2 hours, personally, unless the boys are infants.

Comment: @Aaronut: I was more referring to the fact that the other question was asking about slow cookers, i.e. not exactly the same temperature range. But yes, close enough.