# Food safety after pork loin left in crock pot that was turned off

Tags: food-safety, pork, crockpot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can cooked food be safely stored at room/warm temperature?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/how-long-can-cooked-food-be-safely-stored-at-room-warm-temperature)

I cooked about 2lbs of pork loin in the crock pot for 8 hours on low last night.  It was on low from 12:00am to 8:00am.  From 8:00am to 12:00pm, the crock pot was turned off, and at 12:00pm the food was 'warm' but above room temperature.

Is this still safe to eat?  The crock pot was covered, but its anyones guess (guestimating using some math) how long the loin was at the safe high temperature.  I immediately threw it in the refrigerator, but if I do keep it, should it be brought up to 135°F asap?

I'm waning towards throwing it out.  My wife is pregnant, and we have small children in the house too.

Comment: This has been asked a number of times before. Please also refer to the [food-safety wiki](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info). I'd probably eat it after 4 hours but not offer it to a pregnant woman or small children.